# Chromecast: Is it possible to override the progress sent to sender apps via the Chromecast receiver app?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am trying to report the approximate position of a live stream to our sender apps (user is able to seek around our "live" streams so they are not always at the live edge).

Specifically for Android the value I want to override comes back via the progress listener:

`castSession?.remoteMediaClient?.addProgressListener(progressListener, 1000)`

Currently this value is inaccurate for live streams and I believe it just reports the position in the current window or something.

On the receiver end I've looked into intercepting the MEDIA_STATUS event but this event does not emit frequently enough.

```
player.setMessageInterceptor(
cast.framework.messages.MessageType.MEDIA_STATUS,
status => {
  status.currentTime = {some overridden time here};
  return status;
});
```

Has anyone had success overriding the progress time sent to sender apps?

I suppose one solution might be using a custom callback message the emits every second?

Comment: If you believe this is a bug in the Cast SDK, the please file an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Comment: @LeonNicholls not a bug just curious if theres a way to override/intercept progress listener similarly to how you can intercept MEDIA_STATUS events and such.